# How can I change the crop from one aspect to another in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom-4, cropping, aspect-ratio

If I take a picture in portrait, how can I crop it to a landscape in Lightroom?

I have tried changing the aspect from say 2x3 to 3x2 but it immediately switches back again.

It's sometimes the case that I need to do this but have never figured it out.

It would also be good to crop a landscape from an already cropped portrait, as I often crop a portrait before clients ask for a landscape version. This means they're obviously asking for a crop of the image I see but if I go into change it to a landscape (if I knew how) then it would be hard to re-align everything again.

Answer (score 3):

Press the X key when in the crop tool - this alternates between landscape and portrait orientation.

If you want to discard the cropped part of an image then you would need to either export it once cropped and re-import the cropped version, or use a destructive crop like the one in Photoshop which doesn't retain the entire image after you crop.

Comment: OK I will try that. Do you also know how to crop an already cropped area? I suppose the way I picture it working is to discard the outside-cropped area somehow before cropping again.

Comment: If you want to discard the cropped part of an image then you would need to either export it once cropped and re-import the cropped version, or use a destructive crop like the one in Photoshop which doesn't retain the entire image after you crop.

Comment: The photoshop idea may be a good option. If I edit the image in PS from LR and crop it there then in theory the discarded area won't save into LR. Something for me to try later!

Comment: @connersz I've added my comment as part of the answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

> If I take a picture in portrait, how can I crop it to a landscape in Lightroom?

To change orientation from portrait to landscape (or the other way around) I just drag the corner handle to change the orientation of the crop. The crop box will change size a bit and then suddenly snap into the other orientation. Be sure to use the resize cursor and not the rotate cursor when doing this.

> It would also be good to crop a landscape from an already cropped portrait, as I often crop a portrait before clients ask for a landscape version. This means they're obviously asking for a crop of the image I see but if I go into change it to a landscape (if I knew how) then it would be hard to re-align everything again.

Create a Virtual Copy, and then recrop. The original can stay cropped in the portrait orientation and the Virtual Copy can be cropped to landscape orientation.

Comment: I have tried your first point and it didn't work, it just went back to the original orientation. If you create a virtual copy that also brings across the uncropped area so that wouldn't solve this issue.

Comment: Dragging definitely works to change orientation; perhaps you didn't drag far enough. Yes, the virtual copy brings along the uncropped area but you can create an entirely different crop without destorying the previous one, which I thought was the point.

Comment: When dragging to crop don't use the rotate cursor, but the resize cursor.